# What is real object-oriented (ROO)?

Tags: oop, spring-roo

I recently heard a lot about ROO for "Real object-oriented".

What is all that about ?
Where does it come from ?

Thx

Comment: It's Australian for Object-Oriented, mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROO is a tool released by Spring Source this week: http://www.springsource.org/roo

From a brief investigation, my understanding it that you can generate Java applications dynamically using a mimimal set of configuration.

This is a very early alpha release of code. There's a blog entry that describes its capabilities is at http://stsmedia.net/introducing-spring-roo/

Comment: That doesn't look like it's referring to "real object-oriented" things.

Answer (score 7):

Spring Roo is no longer an acronym for Real Object Oriented (ROO). We changed the case from ROO to Roo to reflect this change. Those interested in a history of the Spring Roo project are encouraged to read the [History section](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/background.html#background-history) of our reference guide, which covers this issue in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

Roo seems more a methodology, a software engeenering stuff than a new technology.

It looks like a budding buzz word.

I would say, nice try for the `Taxonomist` badge with both *roo* and *real-object-oriented* tags.

Answer (score 0):

Check the info in here: http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/tse_hop_into_real_object

Comment: Yes, I've already found that link but the description from Matt Raible isn't very clear for me...

Comment: Or clear for anyone else who has English as their native language.